# NSTableView rowViewAtRow: always returning nil

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to display an `NSPopover` with additional information to a selected row of an `NSTableView`. For that I need to get a reference to the view representation of the selected row so I can "attach" my popover to it:

```
    NSInteger row = [[self membersTableView] selectedRow];
    NSTableRowView *aView = [[self membersTableView] rowViewAtRow: row makeIfNecessary: YES];
    [self setQuickLookPopoverController: [QuickLookPopoverController showPopoverFor: anObject at: aView]];
```

In the above, the result of `aView` is always nil. According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), this is the method to obtain a view object, given a selected row. Especially the last sentence of the discussion is a bit weird:

> Discussion This method will first attempt to return a currently
>   displayed view in the visible area. If there is no visible view, and
>   makeIfNecessary is YES, a prepared temporary view is returned. If
>   makeIfNecessary is NO, and the view is not visible, nil will be
>   returned.
>
> In general, makeIfNecessary should be YES if you require a resulting
>   view, and NO if you only want to update properties on a view only if
>   it is available (generally this means it is visible).
>
> An exception will be thrown if row is not within the numberOfRows. The
>   returned result should generally not be held onto for longer than the
>   current run loop cycle. It is better to call
>   rowViewAtRow:makeIfNecessary: whenever a view is required..

Why is this method always returning nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I used NSTableView's method `(NSRect) rectOfRow: (NSInteger) rowIndex` which will give the frame of the required row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing me the right direction, I had the same problem! I ended up doing the following, but note that I disabled selection of empty rows and that the following code is inside an `IBAction`:

```
    [popOver showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds]
                         ofView:[sender rowViewAtRow:[sender selectedRow]
                                     makeIfNecessary:YES]
                  preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
```